# jQuery UI autocomplete handling selected values in database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Im using jQuery UI autocomplete to populate a few dropdown lists for state/country etc.  When doing an update for the data its part of, I want to set the selected value (if there is a match) based on data in a database. I can set the form values from server code, but how do I then set the autocomplete selected value?

Im poulating the autocomplete boxes with ajax calls.

One method I thought of is to use hidden fields and set those in the code-behind methods, then use jQuery selectors to get those values and set the dropdown selected value.

Comment: From server side when you are getting items check from db and set selected attribute true which matches and returns json,.or view

Comment: Here is the demo of how to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/BbWza/1/    basically you do follwoing $('.ui-autocomplete-input').focus().val('new val');

Comment: Thanks, Im trying that approach now but nothing seems to show in the field im trying to update.  Does the value Im setting have to be one of those in the list that is bound to the field?

Comment: Ok, I used a slightly different selection syntax.  Instead of $('.field_name').val("my new value")  I used $("[id$='field_name']").val("my new value")  This works.   However, I still need to use  the server-side code to update hidden fields, and then update the autocomplete field with the value that was set in the hidden field.   Ehsan - Im not sure I understand the last part of your response.